# How can I access a .txt file which is present in Azure datalake gen2 directly without downloading

Tags: python, azure-data-lake-gen2

How can I access a .txt file which is present in Azure datalake gen2 directly without downloading. I was able to download and read it but is there any way to directly read file from gen2 directly.

I used read_file method DataLakeFileClient() but this method ouputs entire data, is there any way to read the file line by line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use urllib:

```
import urllib.request

file = urllib.request.urlopen('your-txt-file-url')
for line in file:
     print(line.decode().strip())
```

Comment: I want to access all the files in a particular directory in gen2, where I want to use azure identity to authenticate instead of providing URL with SAS token.